# How do I get layout with 2 rows and 2 column with out overlap using bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a layout with navgation bar on top and two rows (second row again divides into two columns ...etc)

I have tried with following code which is dividing the page but overlapping with navigation bar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/CSS/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/CSS/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="btn-group pull-left">
                    <img src="Content/IMAGES/applications.png" alt="logo" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/home/Option">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/home/Option">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/home/Option">Option Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/home/Dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p class="brand">Interface Control Data</p>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <p class="username">Username</p>
                    <img class="logout" src="Content/IMAGES/btn_logout.png" alt="logo" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/Settings">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/KeyboardShortcuts">Keyboard shortcuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/Logout">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%;border:1px solid #aaa;">
        <div class="row-fluid" style="height:100%;border:1px solid #aaa;">
          <div class="span12" style="height:100%;">
                another header
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="row-fluid" style="height:100%;border:1px solid #aaa;">
         <div class="span6" style="height:100%;">
           <div class="row-fluid" style="height:50%;">
             <div class="span12" style="background:blue;height:100%;">a</div>
           </div>
           <div class="row-fluid" style="height:50%;">
             <div class="span12" style="background:red;height:100%;">b</div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="span6" style="height:100%;">
               Right side
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file is

```
    .logout{
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.username {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #777777;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
  background-image:url('../IMAGES/topPanel.png');
}

.navbar-fixed-top .container-fluid{
  background-image:url('../IMAGES/topPanel.png');
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a,
.dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
    background-image:url('../IMAGES/topPanel.png');
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    background-image:url('../IMAGES/topPanel.png');
}
```

Can some one please help me why the navigation bar is overlapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .navbar-fixed-top requires you to add body padding or a margin or padding to the next element on the page. From http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other
>   content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your
>   own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is
>   50px high.
>
> body { padding-top: 70px; } Make sure to include this after the core
>   Bootstrap CSS.

The problem is that you have a fixed height, fixed navigation bar which is taken out of the "document flow" (because it has fixed positioning) so you need to compensate for that by pushing the document or your content down a little.

Comment: It worked in general but If I zoom to extreme level where left hand side and right hand side components in navbar comes one below the other then overlapping problem re-occurs. Is there any mechanism to avoid this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?